# Single Feature in a FeatureCollection?

Tags: geojson

Is it ok to respond with a single item inside a `FeatureCollection` or should I respond with a `Feature` object instead? I'm using `FeatureCollection` in a REST-like server, as index view (`/things.geojson`) as well as show view (`things/3.geojson`), like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ ... ]
      },
      "properties": { ... }
    }
  ]
}
```

I couldn't find anything in the spec, so if it's undefined I'm asking for best practices and references.

Comment: I read http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html so that GeoJSON is a single object which is geometry, feature, or feature collection. With one feature only you can use either plain feature or wrap it inside feature collection. I feel that the latter may have better support in clients.

Comment: Yeah, I though the same thing about clients, but I'm looking for a trusted reference :P

Comment: You do not trust in the GeoJSON specification itself?

Comment: The specification, in this case, does not specify clearly. It's allowed, yeah, by not beign explicitely forbidden... but I would rather read some thoughts on this from an implementation point of view.

Comment: There is a dedicated mailing list geojson-bounces@lists.geojson.org.

Answer (score 1):

Following — for simplicity I'm opting to always have a "FeatureCollection" evenif there is only one element.

Comment: I did the same and didn't have any issues so far :)